# Analog/Digital ground vs Power/Signal ground

Tags: pcb-design, ground-plane

Are these ground plane separations on a PCB equivalent, or if I am already separating my ground into analog and digital parts should I also divide it in power and signal areas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some power ICs require separate power and signal grounds.  This is so the IR drops and switching noise don't impact the current or voltage sense or compensation pin for example.  Generally the power and signal grounds connect at one point often near the power ground of the IC.  This all happens locally on the board and is independent of any digital and analog grounds elsewhere.  If you have discrete power circuitry on the board the same guidelines can help.

Analog vs. digital ground is also usually specified on some ICs, and is also a good idea because it keeps the digital switching noise out of the sensitive analog circuitry which is usually trying to measure something accurately.

So carving up the ground plane locally for all the different purposes is OK and desirable, though sometimes based on experience you can get away with combining "noisy" grounds and "quiet" grounds into single planes.

Comment: "IR drops and switching noise don't impact the current or voltage sense or compensation pin for example". This is also one of the reasons analog and digital grounds are often kept separate. So would it not be enough if the low noise pins were tied to the analog ground and the power pins connected to the digital ground?

Comment: Power grounds often have large switched currents in them.  Any parasitic inductance can cause large voltage spikes.  If your digital circuitry has enough noise margin you might be able to get away with it, but best practice is to keep the power ground currents flowing in a separate plane where you can control where they go and what they affect.